# Support for marathi font

Tags: android, fonts

In my application i want to use marathi font.I know how to use custom fonts in android.The problem is that when i use "Kruti Dev" it shows in android studio preview emulator even thought i have not set it.But if i try to use "Subak" font i am not getting the desired output.
So please can you tell me how will i be able to use this font.

Custom Font Code

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                          "fonts/subak.ttf);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in Android 5.0 that causes some custom fonts to not render when loaded via the `Typeface.createFromAsset()` function.

The workaround is to re-encode the font that is not displaying. Upload the font file to http://www.freefontconverter.com/ and convert it to output as a TTF. Place the outputted file back in your assets folder and it should now display correctly on Android.

This issue was fixed in the Android 5.1 release.

Reference:

https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/02/help-my-custom-font-does-not-work-on-android-5-0/